Debian 12.5 - can't create user - "User ID is not unique/already in use"
I tried to install Eaton Intelligent Power Protector onto a Proxmox 6.5.11-8 machine (based on 12.5 Debian without desktop environment).
Installation failed as the installer could not install the proper user for running the process of the software.
The required UIDs and GID are 998/998. I found that out when I installed the Software onto another Debian 12.5 machine with Xfce. There everything works fine.
When I try to add the user manually, I get the error code from above User ID 998 is not unique/already in use. That seems to be the reason why the installer was not capable of adding it. But I don't find any traces of this user ID on the system ..
Does anybody have a clue why it is possible to create the user on 12.5 with Xfce but not on the Proxmox machine? Running the process with this user having a different ID does not work. Running it with root does fine but of course we don't want that.
Thanks!

Under many Linux distros, UIDs below 1000 are reserved for system use and should not be assigned to users. It should be possible to bypass this constraint, but that might mean modifying the Installer to skip the user creation that you already did. You might glean the existing successful user config to find the exact permissions the installer will need.

adduser has a --system "Create a system account" option. It might be enough to edit this into your Installer script, but it is impossible to know unless you can post that script somewhere like PasteBin.

I would consider an installer requiring userid 998 to be buggy.  The --system option causes userids in reverse sequential order from 999 to be picked, so if some other tool needed a user, 998 is the second most likely pick.   It should either NOT hardcode a specific uid (and let --system pick it) or it should use something much lower, like below 500.  But really, hardcoding a uid in software without having it assigned by a standards body is just dumb.

As the process runs fine with the root user - all I should have to do is create a user that it works with. I tried to create other users with ID and GID < 1000 which is possible but they don't work with the service which then throws SQL error: database object not initialized. So I guess this either is about credentials or wrong user ID. On the working system the user looks like this eaton-ipp:x:998:998::/home/eaton-ipp:/bin/false. The group like that eaton-ipp:x:998. Interesting what you say about the installer. I check back if I can extract the script ..

I found this in the install dir if ! id "eaton-ipp" &>/dev/null; then   sudo useradd "eaton-ipp" -r -s /bin/false   sudo passwd -d "eaton-ipp" fi chown -R "eaton-ipp" "/usr/local/eaton/IntelligentPowerProtector"

References to the id by name are correct. There's nothing in the line ↑ ↑ that requires UID/GID 998

So - guess what? I simply executed the script I posted, a proper user was created ("eaton-ipp", uid 999, gid 997) and the process runs fine. Probably it was about the permissions on the IPP binary why it did not work in my former attempts (and why it ran with root user). Thanks for giving this direction!
